# How can I access Mule ESB Community edition via browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mule, mule-component

I am trying to access it via browser, I had no issue with EE but CE is proving difficult.
On Putty I have it saying:

```
Mule is already running.
```

And when I go to [http://ec2-**-**-**-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8585/](http://ec2-__-__-__-__.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8585/) it won't load properly. I do have the port 8585 open for inbound traffic as well.

Is there something I am forgetting? I haven't used Mule Community Edition before so I've limited knowledge on it.

Comment: So you are running Mule CE in AWS? What's the app you're deploying like? You might have something in there that's EE only.

Comment: I've tried to add an app through Eclipse but when I go export and put in the details it says connection refused

Comment: have you tested your app in Anypoint Studio (install a CE runtime) before deploying?

Comment: If you `pgrep` for Mule processes, how many do you find? The fact it says "Mule is already running" makes us think that you are already running Mule and try to start another one.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. I've managed to get it running as I was not aware of the lack of browser functionality so it confused me

Comment: Voting to close because this question is unclear, has apparently self resolved and won't get any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access to the Mule Management Console (MMC), that is a separate product from Mule ESB and it is only available to manage Mule ESB Enterprise Edition.

In some downloads MMC is included with Mule ESB in a bundle for testing purposes but to run in production you should purchase an Enterprise Edition license.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was mistaken in thinking that CE had some functionality that EE had